# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: kupuvac

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to make two tables for SQLite database,  when I try to insert data to the first table, it works without any error, but when I try to insert data for the second table it gives me error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: kupuvac`
This code for the first table:

```py
db=sqlite3.connect("magacin")

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE magacin(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, model TEXT,
                       proizvoditel TEXT, cena FLOAT , kolicina INTEGER)
''')
```

The code for the second table(the one that gives the error)

```py
db=sqlite3.connect("kupuvac")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE artikli(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        ime_prezime TEXT, ulica TEXT, kontakt TEXT)
''')
```

Here`s the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\Magacin1\1.py", line 8, in <module>
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO kupuvac(ime_prezime, ulica, broj) VALUES(?,?,?)''',(ime, ulica,broj))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: kupuvac
```

Can anyone please tell me what`s wrong and why it gives me an error?

Comment: The error you are showing (that's an `insert` statement) does not relate to the `create table` statement.

Comment: You have code to create tables named `magacin` and `artikli`.  You do not have code that creates a table named `kupuvac`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't supplied code that performs insertion but from what I see in the error I can assume that you passed invalid values for the table name and column names.

Database is "kupuvac" and the table name is "artikli" but you want to insert data into "kupuvac" table which does not exist.